# Omniauth/Devise, authenticating with Twitter works but callback shows failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, twitter-oauth

I send a user to twitter to authorize my application to use their account.

If a user clicks sign in and authenticates correctly then they are sent to the failure method. I can still access their `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` through the hash that is returned. (seems weird to me?)

Whether the user clicks sign in or cancel they are always sent back to the failure method.

Why do they not get sent to the success method when they authenticate correctly?

In my routes file I tried using

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations',
                                     :omniauth_callbacks => "authentications" }
```

but it doesn't ever call the create method, always the failure method.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: authentications_controller.rb

```
class AuthenticationsController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def create
    render :text => 'yes'
  end

  def failure
    render :text => request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end

  alias_method :twitter, :create
end
```

routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :authentications
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'registrations', 
                                       :omniauth_callbacks => "authentications" }
  resources :users
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using pure OmniAuth but you are also using Devise, things are a little bit different:

1. You do not need to define the following route:

   `match '/users/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'`
2. Devise automatically calls methods whose names match the providers'. So if you are logging in with Twitter, you should have a `twitter` method. If you are logging in with Facebook, you should have a `facebook` method.

If you don't want this distinction, and you want all authentications to be directed to the same method (example: `create`), then you can add the following at the **end** of your controller:

```
# authentications_controller.rb
alias_method :facebook, :create
alias_method :twitter, :create
```

This way, you don't have to create `twitter` and `facebook` methods.

Comment: I tried putting alias_method but now i get the error 'undefined method `create' for class `AuthenticationsController''. I definitely have that method in my controller :s. I edited question to include the controller.

Comment: I specifically said "add the `alias_method` at the end of your controller". If you add it at the beginning, before the method is defined, then it will throw an error saying it's undefined.

Comment: If you use `alias_method`, you can also remove that `twitter` method.

Comment: ah yes, I moved it to the bottom but it is still calling the failure method everytime :/. but still returning the hash you would expect when it succeeds :s. i updated the question again with what my controller currently looks like

Comment: Ok, this is definitely weird. You either have another route that is creating some kind of conflict or you need to update your Devise gem. What's your Devise version?

Comment: Yes, so weird! Devise is 3.1.1 and I have updated the question with my routes.rb. I don't see how any of them could cause an issue.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Do you think it is Devise that is causing the issue?

Comment: Is there a way to print the error which is causing it call failure instead of create? All i get in the log is - 

Processing by AuthenticationsController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"87Y3FBTnR48Euqj1o4PoC8EZQV7TqpgmqMLa5PFo8", "oauth_verifier"=>"sQIJWD8TZQLV37K6GlUBJJv2Y6UMjQ77DBv6t47zY"}

Comment: Don't override the `failure` method and see what happens. This is the code that will run: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb#L8-L11

Comment: I get redirected to /users/sign_in/

Comment: and I get the failure message 'Invalid credentials'

Comment: Well, that's pretty obvious then! You are confusing your `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`. Maybe you are using your `access_token` and `access_token_secret` instead.

Comment: Oh no it is definitely sending the twitter hash to the failure method. I can use the access_token and access_token_secret from the hash twitter returns to post tweets via my app. It is just sending it to the failure method for some reason :'(